# Setup a hybrid structure of MVC and React App

Tags: reactjs, .net, asp.net-mvc, react-native, asp.net-core

I'm familiar with the .Net and React applications individually. What I want to do is to create a hybrid app of MVC and React for SaaS. Below are the details,

- .NET MVC application for our website (can't create this in react as
  it is a website and intended to use for google crawl, SEO, and all)
- Once users log in using the MVC application LOGIN form, I want to redirect
  them to ReactApp which is basically a portion after login
- I already have a website built using MVC. Now want to load React application after successful login
- **Note**: This needs to be run under the same domain. No redirection to sub-domain or so. Although, we can have an additional paths like /user

Questions:

- Is it possible to traverse users between both applications?
- Is it possible to manage the same session between the two?

Comment: Hi @DSA, If you want to load react from MVC, you could try iframe. But, I would suggest you try to use react implement mvc, for SEO, you could try to implement seo based on react. Something refer https://github.com/americanexpress/react-seo
Then, it will not have any issue fore share data or user.